# Animating a light in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, lighting

I have an light (of Omni type) and I want it to be a little animated. To be more exactly, I want to imitate a light from a file, so I want it's `attenuationStartDistance` to change value, and same for the `color`. So, it's there any way to run a such sequence on light it's self, or I have to find a little trick to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs:

> [`attenuationStartDistance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNLight_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNLight/attenuationStartDistance): The distance from the light at which its intensity begins to diminish. Animatable.
>
> ...
>
> You can animate changes to this property’s value. See [Animating SceneKit Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012283-CH1-SW6).

For a continuous animation, you can do something like this:

```
let flicker = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "light.attenuationStartDistance")
flicker.fromValue = 100
flicker.toValue = 110
flicker.autoreverses = true
flicker.repeatCount = .infinity
lightNode.addAnimation(flicker, forKey: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more modern way to do this would be to use a custom `SCNAction`:

```
let flickerUp = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 1) { (node, _) in
    node.light?.attenuationStartDistance = 110
}

let flickerDown = SCNAction.customAction(duration: 1) { (node, _) in
    node.light?.attenuationStartDistance = 100
}

let repeat = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.sequence([flickerUp, flickerDown]))
node.runAction(repeat)
```